# C# program keeps asking user input questions more than once

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

enter code here`namespace fuel_consumption {
class Program {
    // Program Reset & exit method at the end of program
    static bool DoItAgain()
    {
        bool startAgain = true;
        string reply = "";

        Console.Write("Start Over? (Y or N):  ");
        reply = Console.ReadLine();
        reply = reply.ToUpper();
        if (reply != "Y") 
        {
            startAgain = false;
        }
        return startAgain;
    }//End DoItAgain method

   //Startup Screen method
    static void WelcomeMessage() {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tWelcome to the Fuel Consumption Calculator\n\n\t");

    }// End startup Screen method

    //Begin user input method for Number of Litres
    static int InputLitres() {
        string userInput = "";
        int selection = 0;
        int minLitres = 20;
        bool inValid = true;

        //User Input Message
        while (inValid) {
            Console.Write("\nEnter the amount of litres consumed:  ");
```

the program keeps asking this question over and over, about 5 times infact.

```
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(userInput, out selection))
                if (selection < minLitres) {
                    // Deliver Error Message to User
                    Console.Write("\nPlease Enter an amount 20 litres or above\n\n Please Try Again:\n");

                }
                else {
                    inValid = false;
                }
        }
        //return the value entered by the user
        return selection;

    }//end InputLitres

    //Begin InputKM method

    static int InputKM() {
        //set user input varibles
        string userInput = "";
        int selection = 0;
        int inputLitres = InputLitres();
        int minKms = 8 * inputLitres;
        bool inValid = true;
        while (inValid) {
            Console.Write("\nEnter Kilometres Travelled: ");
```

Then it asks this question a few times aswell

```
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(userInput, out selection))
                if (selection < minKms) {
                    //Deliver Error Message to user and redirect back to user input of kms
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Minimum Kms is {0:f2} Kilometres, Please Enter a value of {0:f2} or higher", minKms);
                }
                else {
                    inValid = false;
                }
        }
        //return the KM Value
        return selection;

    }//End Input Kms

    static double consumptionCalculation() {
        int litres;
        int kms;
        double litresFormula;
        double formulaResult;


        //Define Base Varibles
        formulaResult = 0.0;
        litresFormula = 0.0;

        litres = InputLitres();

        kms = InputKM();

        //Calculate fuel consumption in litres per 100km

        litresFormula = (double)litres * 100;
        formulaResult = (double)litresFormula / kms;

        {
            //Return the result value
            return formulaResult;
        }
    }

    //Print results method

    static void PrintResults() {
        double kmResult = consumptionCalculation();

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tYour Fuel Consumption is {0} Litres per 100 Kilometres", kmResult);

    }

    //Start Program Loop Method
    static void ProgramLoop() {
        bool startAgain = true;
        //Loop through each user Input Method


        InputLitres();
        InputKM();
        consumptionCalculation();
        PrintResults();


        startAgain = DoItAgain();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args) {


        WelcomeMessage();
        ProgramLoop();

    }
}
```

}

Can anyone give me an idea of where i am going wrong? I just need it to ask those questions once, return the value. Please make it simple as I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: You are calling `InputLitres()` multiple times. If you only want to ask the user once then call it once. The same with `InputKM()`.

Comment: Your main problem is that your not storing your results anywhere that the other methods can retrieve them. You keep calling the input functions. If you don't want to store your results then you should pass the values are parameters.

Comment: Side note: take out the insert code here statement in the first block of code. Its making the other stuff a little harder to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you need to do.

```
void Main()
{
        WelcomeMessage();
        ProgramLoop();
}

static void ProgramLoop()
{
    bool startAgain = true;

    while (startAgain)
    {
        int litres = InputLitres();
        int kms = InputKM(litres);
        double consumption = consumptionCalculation(litres, kms);
        PrintResults(consumption);
        startAgain = DoItAgain();
    }
}

static bool DoItAgain()
{
    Console.Write("Start Over? (Y or N):  ");
    string reply = Console.ReadLine();
    reply = reply.ToUpper();
    return reply.ToUpper() == "Y";
}

static void WelcomeMessage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tWelcome to the Fuel Consumption Calculator\n\n\t");
}

static int InputLitres()
{
    int selection = -1;
    int minLitres = 20;
    bool invalid = true;

    while (invalid)
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter the amount of litres consumed:  ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out selection))
        {
            invalid = selection < minLitres;
            if (invalid)
            {
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter an amount 20 litres or above\n\n Please Try Again:\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

static int InputKM(int litres)
{
    int selection = -1;
    int minKms = 8 * litres;
    bool invalid = true;

    while (invalid)
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter Kilometres Travelled: ");
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out selection))
        {
            invalid = selection < minKms;
            if (invalid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nMinimum Kms is {0:f2} Kilometres, Please Enter a value of {0:f2} or higher", minKms);
            }
        }
    }
    return selection;
}

static double consumptionCalculation(int litres, int kms)
{
    return (double)litres * 100.0 / (double)kms;
}

static void PrintResults(double consumption)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tYour Fuel Consumption is {0} Litres per 100 Kilometres", consumption);
}
```